# Create CMFCPropertyPage class linked to Dialog using Class Wizard in VS2017?

Tags: mfc, cmfcpropertypage

I added a new resource dialog `IDD_PROPPAGE_LARGE`, Assigned it a new ID, title, etc..   Now I launch the class wizard via right click on dialog in resource editor - add class.   It has **Add MFC Class**, I choose base class `CMFCPropertyPage` and Enter my class name, take defaults for .h and .cpp file, leave dialog id set which has the correct ID.

It creates the .cpp/.h file.  I go in there and there is no link to the ID (it creates a simple class derived from `CMFCPropertyPage`, but the constructor doesn't even call it).   More to the issue, I went in to the class wizard to assign the various fields for DDX/DDV and nothing is listed.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA!!

Comment: Sometimes the class wizard mechanism can get corrupt. If you rename your project folder and rename it back (to change the timestamp) with File Explorer it can trigger the class wizard database to be rebuilt. Ofcourse, creating your pages is not enough. You need to have a sheet and add your pages into it.

Comment: Interesting.  In this case I ended up having to manually

     // Dialog Data
    #ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
     enum { IDD = IDD_PROPPAGE_FORTHISONE };
    #endif

in the class declaration in the .h file.  And then add the virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX); via class wizard, then items showed up.